# Xcode running project in network drive

Tags: xcode

[image http://www.notingme.com/stackoverflow.png](http://www.notingme.com/stackoverflow.png)

i'm trying to run project which locates in network drive

but i found that there is some A  M next to the file name , does anyone know what it stands for,

thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is under source control (in example SVN or Git).
This letters mean:
M - Modified (from last commit to source control)
A - Added (this means - haven't commited to source control yet).